# Slideshow in Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I was following this guide on how to make the slideshow with Picture Library. I followed the steps, but it's still not rotating and I'm not sure if I'm forgetting something.

This is inside my Picture Library folder.[image: inside my Picture Library folder]

The slideshow looks like this, but it's not rotating, even when I click the play button.[image: The slideshow looks like this]

I can't do more than 2 links so the tutorial is from SharePoint maven, 'Add a slideshow to a SharePoint site'

Does anyone know if the rotating feature is broken?

Comment: Looks like it is broken according to this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother/picture-library-slideshow-webpart-broken/3e2aaeef-86b5-4d76-ba8d-ad514bb07896

Comment: just a slider library and pull in the pictures through REST

Comment: What do you mean by REST?

Comment: Do you know how to code or are you trying to do it all out of the box?

Comment: I do know, but I was trying to keep it simple and just use the features they provide in Sharepoint.

Comment: I see. The SharePoint slideshow is pretty bad but check the web part settings, maybe there's something there.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I don't have access to server publishing so I can't use slider plugin as an option. Do you have another idea since those are the two common options I've seen?